# Sorting word table items with sub items

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have list in MS Word table.

Items have subitems, each in separate row. Each subitem have indentation. 
I need a way to sort this only items in this list, subitems should move with them.

I have same list in Excel also but I didn't manage to do much with it there too..

Comment: clarify please what should be done with subitems: added to list of items and sorted, or just items should be sorted?

Comment: subitems should keep they place under items after items are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call each item parent, each subitem child. Then following algorithm can be helpful.

1. Give to each parent id
2. To each child assign it's parent id
3. Sort Parents.
4. Display hierarchy again.

Comment: Yura, problem is that subitem (child) deffer from item only in the fact that they have indentation. I need a ways of assigning id 3 to them based on that.

Comment: does it mean, that you need to parse indentation?

Comment: No, subitems (with indentation) should move with their corresponding items (when sorting).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of task:

```
item 1
  subitem1a
   subitem1a1
   subitem1a2
      subitem1b
      subitem1c
item 2
  subitem2a
  subitem2b
```

Suppose you want to sort it by descending, and displayed list should be presented like this:

```
item 2
  subitem2a
  subitem2b
item 1
  subitem1a
   subitem1a1
   subitem1a2
      subitem1b
      subitem1c
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Then algorithm absolutely fits to your needs. at step 1, you'll assign id's to item1 and item 2. to each child assign id's which bind subitem with item. 3. sort paretns. 4. display results

Comment: Idea is not to assign that manually. I have thousands of items and sub-items. I need automatically assign id2 on items based on indentation.

Comment: What about idea to generate and assign id's by C# code?